# Separable Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Does anyone know how to solve the following questions? I haven't learned such questions before, not clear what to do. Can anyone show an detailed example that familar with one of these? Through this way, I can know how to deal with such kind of question, thanks!

[image]

Comment: For the first, rewrite as $y\,dy=\frac{t}{1+t^2}\,dt$. Integrate.

Comment: For the second, rewrite $\frac{\text{dt}}{\text{dy}}=...$ and integrate.

Comment: What have you tried?  The link "asking help" on the ask a question page links here [ http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask ] and this suggests ways to improve your likelihood of getting an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, if you have $\dfrac{dy}{dt}=A(t,y)$, the equation is separable if $A(t,y)=f(t)g(y)$ by integrating $\dfrac{dy}{g(y)}=f(t)dt$.

In this case, we have $f(t)=\frac{t}{t^2+1}$ and $g(y)=\frac{1}{y}$. So we have $ydy=\frac{t}{t^2+1}dt$ and you can integrate both sides.

Comment: after integrate, I get: (1/2)(y^2)=(1/2)ln(1+t^2)+C is it what the question asked? or I need to solve y in terms of t and C?

Comment: Good! Now solve for $y$.

Comment: is it: /y/ = (ln(1+t^2)+2C)^(1/2) ?

Comment: Yes, that is pretty much correct! But I would write it as $y =[ln(1+t^2)]^{1/2}+C$, since we are usually given an initial value $y(0)$ and it is awkward to write $2C$ instead.

Comment: Thanks! for these kind of question, is y=(+/-) [ln(1+t^2)]^(1/2)+C the final answer? or is there anything more I need to do?

Comment: That is the final answer! It does ask you to find the general solution, without specifying an initial condition.

Comment: Thank you for your kindly help!!!

Comment: No problem! Glad to help.

Comment: for the 2nd Qs, I get: ln[1-y^2]=-2t+C --> [1-y^2]=e^(-2t+C), but how can I deal with y(0)=-2? does it mean to sub y=0 in it?

Comment: Check again. $\frac{y}{1-y^2}y=dt$. Integrate both sides and solve for y.

Comment: -(1/2)ln[1-y^2]=t+c --> ln(1-y^2)=-2t-2c --> ln(1-y^2)=-2t+C --> y=(+/-)1+[e^(-27+c)]^(1/2)

Answer (score 1):

Use the hint for both of Separation of Variables and then integrate each side.

For the first, separate and write:

$$\int y~dy = \int \dfrac{t}{t^2-1}~dt$$

For the second, separate and write:

$$\int \dfrac{y}{1 - y^2}~dy = \int dt, y(0) = -2$$

You should now be able to resolve them both.

Comment: for the first, I get: (1/2)(y^2)=(1/2)ln(1+t^2)+C does it finish, or I need to solve y in terms of t?